# Use Angular library in my project without publishing

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I created Angular library My-lib , and I'm trying to use it in my application My-app
but I don't want to publish it to NPM repo.
I tryied to do the npm link after I build My-lib `npm link /folder/My-lib/dist/My-lib` and then in My-app folder `npm link My-lib`

But it didn't work, `No package.json found`, so I did the `npm link` on the root folder of the library
and from My-app folder `npm link full-path-to/My-lib`, there I can see My-lib in the node-modules of My-app
but when I try to import it get can't find module.

Is there a way to do this , or maybe I'm not doing the npm link the right way !

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to use lerna or nx.

Comment: You can do a file:// link to the .tgz file directly in package.json?

Comment: Or simply import the public_api directly if it’s inside the same project..?

Comment: @MikeOne can you give more information plz ?

Comment: Sure. In your build lib (dist) folder - is there a .tgz file?

Comment: @MikeOne, No there's not , acctully now the Link works , but I have an error " Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ApplicationRef -> NgZone]: "

Comment: I used npm pack , and now I got the .tgz file

Comment: So yiou can now, in your application package.json just use myLib: 'file://../../path.to.tgzfile'. Once you added that, just run npm i myLib and it will install it

Comment: @MikeOne cool it's working , thx man,
do you know how to make the changes done in Mylib reflect directly to Myapp ?

Comment: That is only possible (I think) if you have your lib inside your app. You can then make a path entry in tsconfig that points to your public_api. However, you’d still have to build your lib everytime.. but it saves you from having to npm install it every time.

Comment: @MikeOne, thank you man you were a great help.

Answer (score 6):

```
cd lib/dist/My-lib
npm pack
```

- This will create a package tgz file which you can install directly in your app using by referring to this compressed file.

```
npm install ../dist/My-lib/My-lib-0.0.1.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd lib/dist/My-lib
npm pack
```

once the *.tgz* is created inside *lib/dist/My-lib* then just pack it.
generally *npm publish* do the

> npm pack

behind the scene before publishing this is the artifact that is actually used when do

> npm i My-lib

so in package.json

under dependencies you can include like

...
"My-lib" : --the path to your My-lib-0.0.1.tgz--
...

like

> "My-lib" : "../My-lib-0.0.1.tgz"